# Excel VBA - Cell change, datestamp in a column

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create two date stamps, one for OK and one for NOT OK. The values are filled in in column A and are `'x' for OK` and `'NOK' for NOT OK`.

When 'x' is filled in in column A, the value in column 49 should be the datestamp when 'x' is filled in.

When 'NOK' is filled in in column, the value in column 52 should be the datestamp when 'NOK' is filled in.

Also, if 'x' or 'NOK' is removed from column A, so should the datestamp dissappear. This is what I have.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '49 = ok
    '52 = NOK

    Dim KeyCells As Range

    ' The variable KeyCells contains the cells that will
    ' cause an alert when they are changed.
    Set LastRow = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:" & LastRow)

    If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Like "*x*" Then
        Cells(Row, 49).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If

    If Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) Like "*NOK*" Then
        Cells(Row, 52).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: where are you stuck with? you know that `Set KeyCells = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` does not work, because ROW returs a rownumber - not a range?

Comment: Oh, let me quickly fix this then. Maybe it'll work.

Comment: you did not define `Row` in `Cells(Row,` ;)

Comment: Ok, I edited my range normally. Still doesn't do anything, I also added it to this worksheet.

Comment: Hmmm I think I've misunderstood the Worksheet_Change sample (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213612).

Comment: it struck me right now - this will be called double, because you are changing a cell within the macro and you are reacting to any changes of cells - might want to use disabled events.

Comment: What do you mean? Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought this would be triggered if a cell is changed in column A. It then looks to see if the cell contains 'x' or 'NOK', if it does the cell in column 49/52 receive a datestamp?

Comment: not quite - Worksheet_Change will be called on ANY change of cell-content - by user or code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here, try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    '49 = ok '52 = NOK
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    With Target
    'check if change happend in column A
    If .Column = 1 Then
      'check if changed value is X
      If .Value Like "*x*" Then
          'add datestamp if it is
          Cells(.Row, 49).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      Else
          'clear datestamp if not
          Cells(.Row, 49).Value = ""
      End If

      If .Value Like "*NOK*" Then
          Cells(.Row, 52).Value = Format(DateTime.Now, "yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
      Else
          Cells(.Row, 52).Value = ""
      End If
    End If
    End With
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It looks like it should work, but for some reason it isn't :s I added this code to ThisWorkbook.

Comment: ah - now i get it - no, you would have to add this to your worksheet! if cou have multiple worksheets, then you should export the contents of my routine to a subroutine like `Sub OnColumnAChange(ByVal Target as Range)` and call it from each Worksheet_Change of each Worksheet this is needed.

Comment: another way would be using the `Workbook_SheetChange` event, but then you would have to adapt `Cells` to `Sh.Cells` - i think. I don't now right now if this event would be triggered on other ocasions too.

Comment: It works! I didn't know there was a difference between ThisWorkbook and the Sheets. I have always used Modules for my macros.

Comment: You should be disabling `Events` - this code will call itself again when it makes changes

Comment: Added With-Statement and disabled Events ;)